# Compare datetime mysql and flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pymysql

I am trying to compare two datetimes and it's showing sql syntax error

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify
from datetime import datetime
import pymysql

app = Flask(__name__)

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        host = "localhost"
        user = "test"
        password = "test123"
        db = "test"
        self.con = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, db=db, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()


@app.route('/getCameraTypeAndTime/<string:date1>/<string:date2>', methods=['GET'])
def getCameraTypeAndTime(date1,date2):
    start = datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end = datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    db=Database()
    result1=db.cur.execute("Select camera, COUNT(*) as freq from face_log group by camera where timestamp>start and timestamp_end<end")
    return jsonify({'result': result1})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The format in sql is datetime but it won't compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are trying to compare column values to `START` and `END` [MySQL keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) not your `start` and `end` variables. You need to make a query with placeholders and pass your variables to it like this (according to [PyMySQL documentation](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL#documentation)):

```py
db.cur.execute("""
    SELECT camera, COUNT(*) AS freq FROM face_log
    WHERE timestamp > %s and timestamp_end < %s
    GROUP BY camera
""", start, end)
```

Also note that `GROUP BY` part of the SQL query must be after `WHERE` part.